# I am not able to fill the round corners with color using css?

Tags: html, css

I have made two `div` tags in html and the outermost div tag has round corners but when I try to fill the inner `div` with color but there is some white space left above inner `div` (see screenshot for more clarification). I want  to fill the colour entirely for `class-"header"`. I want to fill the white space near upper corners with blue color.

```css
#widget {
  position: fixed;
  left: 340px;
  top: 75px;
  width: 450px;
  height: 500px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.container {
  background-color: #0071B3;
  width: 450px;
  height: 250px;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="widget">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h4>Let's Enhance</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The blank space on the top of the `.container` is caused by the `margin-top` of the `h4` element. You can replace it with a `padding top` and add an `overflow:hidden` on the `#widget` to prevent any content (here the square corners) to overflow.

Here is a working snippet.

```css
#widget {
    position: fixed;
    width: 450px;
    height:500px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 1px;
    box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0;
    border-radius: 10px;
    
    overflow:hidden;
}

.container{
    background-color: #0071B3;
    width:450px;
    height:250px;
}

.header{
    text-align: center;
}

h4{
  margin-top: 0;
  padding-top:1rem;
}
```

```html
<div id="widget">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
        <h4>Let's Enhance</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
     <div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I could not understand ?

Comment: I just want to fill header div with below colo below that it should be white.

Comment: @stonerock I added a working snippet to be more clear

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to color the entire widget, put the background color on `#widget` instead of `.container`.

If instead you only want `.container` colored but without the extra whitespace before it, you can either remove the top margin of the header, or set `.container` to `display:inline-block`. You'll also need to add an `overflow:hidden` to the parent to prevent the color overflowing the border radius:

```css
#widget {
  position: fixed;
  left: 340px;
  top: 75px;
  width: 450px;
  height: 500px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.container {
  background-color: #0071B3;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 450px;
  height: 250px;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="widget">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h4>Let's Enhance</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Is that what you want?
If yes, you should apply the `background-color` on the `#widget`, and not on the `.container`.
I've only moved 1 line of your code.
Check the comments in the CSS:

```css
#widget {
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #0071B3;  /* ADDED HERE */
  /* left: 340px; /* Removed for better visibility in the snippet */
  /* top: 75px;   /* Removed for better visibility in the snippet */
  width: 450px;
  height: 500px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 1px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 4px 0;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

.container {
  /* background-color: #0071B3; /* REMOVED FROM HERE */
  width: 450px;
  height: 250px;
}

.header {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="widget">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="header">
      <h4>Let's Enhance</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="info">
      <div>
      </div>
    </div>
```